# Disable and highlight a row in gridview when delete command field delete button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, highlighting

I want to **Highlight and disable** a gridview row on delete button click. I am using a data table and binding it to the grid and changing the flag **IS_DELETED='Y'** when user clicks delete button . The Delete button is currently in command field. As soon as the user clicks on the delete button it should disable the row and hide the buttons so that it restricts the user from further edits. Can some please help me in resolving this issue. This has been troubling me since long. Thanks is advance.

[image]

Comment: You can use jQuery to hide buttons and add some class to the row to highlight it. You need to handle button click and then change it's parent row. That's the idea...

Comment: Can you please post the code on how to do that? i am a newbie for C# and Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbaYa/) as a basic sample using jQuery. Google about jQuery in you need. Again - you need to handle button click and then change it's parent row.

```
$('input.delete').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').find('input.button').hide().end().addClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: Hi Lavrik, Thanks for the code snippet. It looks like this example is for table and button controls. Can you please tell me how to use this for a gridview?

Comment: You can see the row markup and apply it to these markup. Anyway gridview is just a html on the client side. I suppose there are more proper way of doing it asp.net webforms but i'm mostly use mvc. @drum answer may help you.